# Default algorithm of StandardPBEStringEncryptor

Tags: jasypt

What is the default algorithm used by [StandardPBEStringEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html)? In the Jasypt core api [JavaDoc](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/index.html); I see a [setter](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html#setAlgorithm(java.lang.String)) to set the algorithm, but no corresponding getter.

I was able to use this class without calling [setAlgorithm()](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html#setAlgorithm(java.lang.String)) and hence I wonder what is the default that it used and how did it determine to use that default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jasypt version 1.9.2 it is PBEWITHMD5ANDDES.